# how to compare two Dictionaries values with same keys but different values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have these two dictionaries and I need to compare the values with the same key.

Dict1={
1, "blue"
2, "yellow"
3,"red"}

Dict2={
1, "red"
2, "yellow"
3, "red"}

for instance, compare the values with key 1 and return false. But when it compares the values of key 2 returns true.

Comment: what is type of your values in `Dict1` and `Dict2`? is it string?

Comment: Please show the declaration of the dictionary and the code needed to populate them with the values. Also show the code you have tried to use.

Comment: the key and the values are string

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it is pretty concise and will help you get better answers, faster. This is not a code writing service, please post your attempt at solving the problem and we will gladly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with these solution. Here you go through the dict1 keys, and when you find a similar key in dict2, you compare the values of that key in each dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string k in dict1.Keys){
   if (dict2.ContainsKey(k))
   {
       bool compareValues = (dict1[k] == dict2[k]);
   }
}
```

Hope it works, tell us if you have another problem!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
          Dictionary<int, string> d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "blue"},
                {2, "yellow"},
                {3, "red"},
                {4, "black"}
            };

            Dictionary<int, string> d2 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                {1, "purple"},
                {2, "yellow"},
                {3, "red"},
                {4, "red"}
            };

            var d3 = d2.Where(x => d1[x.Key] == x.Value)
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: The key is string too

Comment: The same logic will still work. Just declare the dictionaries like below  EDITED  Dictionary<string, string> d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"1", "blue"},
                {"2", "yellow"},
                {"3", "red"},
                {"4", "black"}
            };

            Dictionary<string, string> d2 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"1", "purple"},
                {"2", "yellow"},
                {"3", "red"},
                {"4", "red"}
            };